# Magento - sales_flat_quote `reserved_id` not being released for some customers

Tags: magento

EDIT:

It appears that under some circumstances (which I have yet to determine) the reserved_id field is not being reset/cleared for some customers. Therefore, when a very small percentage of customers log in after performing a successful transaction their quote_id is being assigned the value of that in the sales_flat_quote table.

Therefore when they try to place the order we are seeing integrity constraint violation errors in the logs - such as:

"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation 1062 Duplicate entry "

This is beginning to look like a core bug but Its completely un-reproducible at the moment.

Magento version 1.5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the database repair tool? It can be found at http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool. It seems like yo need to repair your database.

Comment: Unfortunately - the database is fine.  I have checked it.

Comment: Did you install a custom module? I would just try to run the database repair tool if I were you and see what happens.